# geb as an additional module using android studio cant find GebConfig.groovy

Tags: android-studio, grails, groovy, geb

I get the error `Caught: geb.error.NoBaseUrlDefinedException: There is no base URL configured and it was requested.`

My main module, i assume is default because its got a green dot at the bottom right, is called app and runs some appium tests.

This module called website(little blue line thing) has a java package called geb where both GebConfig.groovy and my groovy script are located. It's very simple:

```
package geb;
import geb.Browser

Browser.drive {
    go("/some/site")
}
```

and my config:

```
package geb

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver

path = 'c:\\drivers\\'


waiting {
    timeout = 2
    retryInterval = 0.5

    preset{
        slow{
            timeout = 20
            retryInterval = 1
        }
        verySlow{
            timeout = 50
        }
    }
}

environments {
    chrome {
        drive='chromedriver.exe'
        system='webdriver.chrome.driver'
        fpath= path+drive
        System.setProperty(system,fpath)
        driver = { new ChromeDriver() }
    }
    ie {
        drive='IEDriverServer.exe'
        system='webdriver.ie.driver'
        fpath= path+drive
        System.setProperty(system,fpath)
        driver = { new InternetExplorerDriver() }
    }

}
driver = {new InternetExplorerDriver()}
baseUrl = "http://www.google.com"
reportDir = 'c:\\reports\\'
```

I have tried manually setting the buildurl to no avail, I've gone through the manual but i couldnt get the classpath set, or atleast when i tried that gave me a whole new set of issues.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In your GebConfig try renaming 'baseURL' to 'baseUrl'

Comment: That was one of the things I had tried. I did also try to set the `geb.build.baseUrl` from the config file so
`geb.build.baseUrl=http://www.google.com` also doesn't work. I've corrected the code in the main question now

Comment: any one got any ideas? this classpath thing is making me scratch my head